# Sort columns in a TableForm

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, output, display

I have a list in the form

```
join = {{3, {-5, 4, 4}}, {6, {2, -1, -1}}, {7, {-105, 32, 
104}}, {8, {-1, 1, 
2}}, {8, {18, -12, -16}}, {9, {217, -52, -216}}, {10, {-171, 130, 
141}}, {10, {4, -3, -3}}}
```

I've done the following:

```
len = Length[DeleteDuplicates[First[Transpose[join]]]]

TableForm[Table[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[GatherBy[join, First][[i]],1], {i,1,len}],TableDepth->2]
```

to get the output grouped by the first element (the single number, i.e. 3, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10) and displayed as a `TableForm`.

The three-element sublists contain either one or two negative numbers. I would like to have the `TableForm` arranged so that in the second column there will be only those containing one negative number, and in the third column only those with two negative numbers. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you look at Dataset? This provides quite some options on what you might be looking for.

Comment: please test your code. There are mistakes in the line with TableForm[...

Comment: @MockupDungeon I don't see how I could use `Dataset`. @JohnConorCosnett Sorry, I lost one bracket; it's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join = {{3, {-5, 4, 4}}, {6, {2, -1, -1}}, {7, {-105, 32, 
     104}}, {8, {-1, 1, 
     2}}, {8, {18, -12, -16}}, {9, {217, -52, -216}}, {10, {-171, 130,
      141}}, {10, {4, -3, -3}}};
table = {#, {}, {}} & /@ Union[First /@ join];
AppendTo[table[[#1 /. 
       Thread[Union[First /@ join] -> Range@Length@table], 
      Total@Map[Boole@*Negative, #2] + 1]], #2] & @@@ join;
table // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]